# Era uma vez um gato maltês tocava piano e falava francês

Tags: etimologia, coloquialismos

I am looking for a canonical version of the children's poem:

> Era uma vez um gato maltês tocava piano e falava francês

To the extent of my understanding of Portuguese, the versions in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvQzvkFilbE) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1dAPFeeBRs) are not the same. In addition, there seem to be a competing poem about *gato xadrez*.

Is there really a more canonical version or are there many competing variations with approximately equal popularity? Or perhaps there are ones more typical for Portugal and others for Brasil?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are tons of these, by color.
xadrez by the way means checkered and there are no checkered cats, except in drawings.

Such as in the book [Era uma vez um gato xadrez...](https://www.ipirangadonorte.mt.gov.br/fotos_escola/3091.pdf):

> Era uma vez um gato **xadrez**.
> Caiu da janela e foi só uma vez.
>
> Era uma vez um gato **azul**.
> Levou um susto e fugiu para o sul.
>
> Era uma vez um gato **vermelho**.
> Entrou no banheiro e fez cara no espelho.

There are other colors in the book: **amarelo, verde, colorido, laranja, marrom, rosa, preto, branco.**
I don't want to copy every single one. That lady author, Bia Villela, did a great job of the colors and the ditty.

That said, you can make one up.

Era uma vez um gato fofinho, que mal saltava por ser tão gordinho.

[mal + a verb = hardly]

Here is another Portuguese one:

> “Era uma vez,
>
> um gato maltês,
>
> tocava piano e falava francês.
>
> Queres que te conte outra vez?”

[Education article by Hugo Manuel Soares de Brito](http://www.barometro.com.pt/2017/07/19/era-uma-vez-um-gato-maltes-tocava-piano-e-falava-frances/).

In Brazil, depending on the location of the speaker, the queres tu form might become queer.